# JavaScript Empty Array indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

I went through some JS code last day, but I couldn't understand. Here is the code

```
var data = {
     name : 'Mr John',
     age : '29',
     location : 'New York',
     profession : 'Accoutant'
};

var allowedNull = [];

for (var i in data) {
     if (!data[i])
     {

          if (allowedNull.indexOf(i) < 0)
          {
               console.log('Empty');
          }
     }
}
```

The script actually prints "Empty" in console if the `data` has an empty property. I just wanted know, how it works by calling `indexOf` on `allowedNull` . Can somebody explain how this works.

Fiddle : [Check](https://jsfiddle.net/1ahuh0qt/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all the `indexOf(i)` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
In this case the flow is:

```
//loop over data object

for (var i in data) {

//if the current property is empty/undefined
 if (!data[i])
 {
      //and if this property is not present inside the allowedNull array
      if (allowedNull.indexOf(i) < 0)
      {
           // print empty
           console.log('Empty');
      }
 }
}
```

If you try to add in the data object the property `test : ''` you'll get printed in the console `Empty` but if you add `test` inside the allowedNull array `var allowedNull = ['test']` nothing will be printed.

Hope this can help! :)

Comment: Actually the allowedNull is not required in my code, as its empty and  not in use. Some misinterpretations. :|  Anyways thanks for the help ;)